# SharePoint 2013 - InfoPath form using REST API and cannot get the data

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

Environment: SharePoint 2013 Online & InfoPath form 2013

I'm try to make a data collection using REST API and using a button to trigger the action.

When I preview the form & press the button first time, I get the error as below

**The query cannot be run for the following DataObject: Document in Dev
InfoPath cannot run the specified query.

The file is not a valid XML file.

Some form data cannot be retrieved bacause InfoPath is operating offline mode.
Form elements, such as drop-down lists, may be blank. Ensure that you have network connectivity and that InfoPath is online mode.**

---

When I Click the button second time , it can be receive the data.

When I publish the form to SharePoint, I will get the error every time when i press the button

**XML data that is required for this form to function correctly cannot be found.

An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. 

Log ID:5566**

---

Any Idea??
I can get the correct data when I directly access the REST API link.

Comment: Please post the code how you call the file

Comment: Also need help on this issue

Answer (score 1):

You must add `?NoRedirect=true` when downloading the file

```
file.xml?NoRedirect=true
```

Comment: did you mean update the REST URL from../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('hkbnFormLibrary')/items to ../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('hkbnFormLibrary')/items?NoRedirect=true  ??  If Yes  , this solution is not work for me.

Comment: No, to the actual file you are downloading. How do you call it?

Comment: e.g.REST Call URL: https:// siteurl/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TestingDocuments')/items?$orderby=FormID%20desc&$top=1

Comment: using the InfoPath Data Collection function, create a REST Web service and using this url https:// siteurl/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TestingDocuments')/items?$orderby=FormID%20desc&$top=1

Comment: Hi guys, any luck how to call rest api using infopath 2013

Answer (score 0):

Same error (400 bad request) cost me much time. My working solution is adding `NoRedirect=true` at the end of my URL:

```
http://server/qa/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={***E885}&XMLDATA=TRUE&noredirect=true
```

Ref:
https://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/the-form-cannot-run-the-specified-query-in-infopath-2007-forms-migrated-to-sharepoint-2010/#comment-564